# Forms html merg values or add an value on send

Tags: php, html, forms

I dont know if this is even possible without javascript but i want an form input and when i send the form it should add some text on the value.

```
<form method="post" action="https://somesite.com">
<input name="snapname" style="width: 177px; margin-top: 340px;"  type="text" placeholder="Your username">
<input type="Submit" name="send">
</form>
```

So right now the form sends the value that is typed from the user in the browser.
Is there an way for me to add text when i send the form that the user cant see? Do i need to do it in javascript? Or is it possible in HTML? HTML5?

For example lets say the user writes adam
The value of snapname is now adam
When they click submit it will submit it as adam
But what i want is to add text to the value.
So i want mytext+adam to be the value of snapname where mytext is a static value.

I do not want to use javascript if i dont need to. Is it a good idea to use some kind of redirect php script? And let the script add the text and then send the users to the correct webadress with right value?

Comment: Is the form submitting to an eternal site? If yes then use javascript, if not, just add the string in your form handling code

Comment: Yes its submitting to an external site

Comment: Ok, then javascript it the simplest solution, i have written an answer  with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are submitting to an external site your best bet will be to use javascript. You can remove the name from the visible input (so its data is not submitted), add a hidden field with the correct name, then populate the hidden fields value with javascript:

```
<form method="post" action="https://somesite.com">
    <input onkeyup="appendvalue(this.value);"  type="text" placeholder="Your username">
    <input name="snapname" type="hidden" id="snapname">
    <input type="Submit" name="send">
</form>

<script>
function appendvalue(userval){

    var append = "somestring";
    var hidden = document.getElementById("snapname");
    hidden.value = userval+append;

}

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you i will approve this even thought i did not want javascript i think its the only way of doing it and yeah it works great! So thank you so much for that. SUPERB

Comment: Glad i could help, and yes if you want to post data and have the users browser follow the redirect, i think javascript is the only option

Answer (score 2):

Use javascript or simply:

```
$my_var = "My Text" . $_POST['snapname'];
```

And then use this variable in php.

Comment: How is this suppose to work? I need to send the form to another site so it needs to be edited before it sends it away or a PHP redirect page that build the new post and redirect it to the right page but i havent found any information how to redirect with post command

Comment: Hi thanks yeah i have used curl before but for this it wont work i need to send the post information and redirect the user to the same page. its a payment page. But i had to use javascript i was trying to do a php redirect script but dident know how to post the headers.

Comment: You can send post requests easily via curl

Comment: @FaizAhmed the salient point here is that the users browser must follow the post redirect. You cannot do this with curl

Answer (score 1):

PHP is going to be your best bet here, as Faiz said above create a simple variable and extend the $_POST['snapname'] to include what you need.

Comment: This form is sent to a site i do not own. So i need to change it before the external site gets the information from me.

Comment: Why dont you process the form within the same file (something I do all the time). For example: `<form action="" method="post">` Then you process this before you start your doctype etc etc. This is how I handle most forms in any PHP project I do. Then pass the information over to the external script.